# Find, select, and copy row

Tags: excel, vba

How do I find a cell containing a certain string in a certain column, then select the entire row and copy that row using Excel vba?

I am relatively new to using Excel VBA and have spent days trying to code this myself.
I am working on a worksheet in which different datasets are copied into. Every data set will contain the string "page" in some cell of column A, however the row varies from dataset to dataset. I now need some vba code to first identify the cell of column A that contains the string "Page", then select that entire row and copy it below the last row of the table (whose number of rows also varies). I already managed to write some code that copies an entire row to the bottom of the table so I could also reuse that code, the main issue is with identifying the right row that contains the string.
Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"I already managed to write some code"* please add your code in the question above ([edit]), and describe where you got stuck or errors. Also do some research on how to use the [Range.Find method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) and try to use that to find your string "Page". • Also some good example (or screenshot) of how your worksheet/data looks like helps a lot to understand your question. And see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
Sub test()

    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim ColumnNo As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim rngFound  As Range
    Dim wsDestination As Worksheet, wsSource As Worksheet
    
    'set worksheets
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set wsSource = .Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set wsDestination = .Worksheets("Overview")
    End With
    
    'Set the value you want to search
    strSearch = "*Page*"
    
    'Set the column you want to seach
    ColumnNo = 1
    
    'Create a with statement to point Sheet1.
    With wsSource
        
        'Search for strSearch in column number ColumnNo
        Set rngFound = .Columns(ColumnNo).Find(strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        
        If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
            LastRow = wsDestination.Cells(wsDestination.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            'Copy row.
            .Rows(rngFound.Row).EntireRow.Copy
            'Paste row
            wsDestination.Rows(LastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            'Delete row
            .Rows(rngFound.Row).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Else
            'Msg box
            MsgBox "Value not found."
        End If
        
    End With
      
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much - It now seems to be working - but now I have an issue with the paste section, this is what I have there: 

` If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
            .Columns(rngFound.Row).EntireRow.Copy
               Worksheets("Overview").Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).offset(1,0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .Columns(rngFound.Row).EntireRow.Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
       
        End If`

        It gives me an error message that says that the copied range and the paste range differ, do you know how to account for that? 
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: btw, how do i add code as a comment? So sorry, but as you can see I am an absolute bloody beginner with both VBA and stackoverflow

Comment: Hi guys, I know need some code to paste a value in H2 from worksheet(3) to the column M and row that contains the string "Page". I tried copying and adjusting the code that you already wrote, but i do not get it to worl. How can i specify that i want to paste the value in column M?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code to copy entire rows from sheet called Sheet1 to another sheet called Sheet2 with criteria "Page"

```
Private Sub test()
Dim i As Integer, lastrow As Integer, newrow As Integer
lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To lastrow
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i) Like "*" & "Page" & "*" Then
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Copy
Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
newrow = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(newrow, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: There are a few issues with your code: 1. You should use `Long` data type rather than `Integer` as last row could very easily be beyond the scope of an `Integer` data type. 2. The way you are getting the value for `lastrow`, `Row.Count` will get the row count from active sheet which may not be **Sheet1**. 3. You shouldn't use things like `Select` or `Activate`. They slow the process down and have no actual use: hence why they are frowned upon. Hope this helps