# Find string and paste other value in other column but same row vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on a macro for a dataset. The macro needs to find the row of the string "page" in column A and then paste another value from worksheet(3) to column M and in the same row as "page". I already have some code from a previous question [Find, select, and copy row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63629194/find-select-and-copy-row) but I do not know how to specify that i want to paste in column M and the same row as the string.

Here is what I have:

```
With ThisWorkbook
        Set wsSource = .Worksheets("Overview")
        Set wsDestination = .Worksheets("Overview")
    End With
    
    'Set the value you want to search
    strSearch = "*Page*"
    
    'Set the column you want to seach
    ColumnNo = 1
    
    'Create a with statement to point Sheet1.
    With wsSource
        
        'Search for strSearch in column number ColumnNo
        Set rngFound = .Columns(ColumnNo).Find(strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        
        If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
            LastRow = wsDestination.Cells(wsDestination.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            'Copy row.
            .Rows(rngFound.Row).EntireRow.Copy
            'Paste row
            wsDestination.Rows(LastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            'Delete row
            .Rows(rngFound.Row).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
       
        End If
        
    End With
```

I now need to adjust the code as specified above. Can somebody help me please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: The cell in question then would be `wsDestination.Range("M" & rngFound.Row)`.

Answer (score 0):

If your data only repeat once then this code is okay..But if your text "page" repeat multiple times then you need to use Findnext function..Here is a code which will return the range of cells which contain page text..then you need to use for each cell in range and calculate the row number..

```
'Uses Range.Find to get a range of all find results within a worksheet
' Same as Find All from search dialog box
'Where search start from First cell and go to last cell.So that we say that search start after lastcell = .cells(.cells.count)
Function FindAll(rng As Range, What As Variant, Optional LookIn As XlFindLookIn = xlValues, Optional LookAt As XlLookAt = xlPart, Optional SearchOrder As XlSearchOrder = xlByRows, Optional SearchDirection As XlSearchDirection = xlNext, Optional MatchCase As Boolean = False, Optional MatchByte As Boolean = False, Optional SearchFormat As Boolean = False) As Range
'For containing matched range.
Dim SearchResult As Range
'For first matched address.
Dim firstMatch As String
With rng
    'Find first Matched result.
    Set SearchResult = .Find(What, .Cells(.Cells.count), LookIn, LookAt, SearchOrder, SearchDirection, MatchCase, MatchByte, SearchFormat)
    'If SearchResult <> Nothing then set the firstmatched range address to the variable.
    If Not SearchResult Is Nothing Then
        firstMatch = SearchResult.Address
        Do
            If FindAll Is Nothing Then
                'FindAll = nothing then set FindAll = first match cell
                Set FindAll = SearchResult
            Else
                'If FindAll contain some range then union previous range with new match result range.
                Set FindAll = Union(FindAll, SearchResult)
            End If
            'Change the SearchResult to next matched cell.
            'FindNext will start from previous SearchResult address.
            Set SearchResult = .FindNext(SearchResult)
        'Loop until the SearchResult contains no address or address <>first address.
        Loop While Not SearchResult Is Nothing And SearchResult.Address <> firstMatch
    End If
End With
End Function
```

Your sending range will be Column A..range("A:A")...and if you want partial match or whole match then you need to pass that variable or set default value to your convenient option..And if you just want to return the array which contain only just row number then add variant as output of function and change the function accordingly...If you need anything else then comment here.